# ¿Por qué llamamos "fondo de armario" al guardarropa básico de una persona?

Tags: expresiones, ropa

Seguro que alguna vez habéis ojeado una revista de moda y os habéis encontrado con referencias al *fondo de armario*.

Por ejemplo, en Vogue, y bajo el título [Las prendas que tienes que tener](http://www.vogue.es/moda/tendencias/articulos/prendas-basicas-que-tienes-que-tener/21268), comentan:

> Unos lo llaman **fondo de armario**, otros simplemente básicos... Lo cierto es que, a pesar de las tendencias que se esfuerzan en hacernos creer que han venido para quedarse cada temporada, hay un puñado de prendas que se sitúan por encima de cualquier estética o corriente con fecha de caducidad. **Son las prendas que hay que tener, o en su defecto, aquellas de las que nunca debes deshacerte porque siempre, siempre, acaban volviendo.**

La cita lo dice todo: se refiere a aquellas prendas en base a la cual se sustenta el estilo de uno. Después, uno añade complementos que van variando según la temporada, el día, etc. Por ejemplo, unos vaqueros podrían definirse como *fondo de armario*, mientras que unas pulseras o una camiseta son cosas más fútiles.

Lo que me parece curioso del concepto es su nombre en sí: para mí, en el fondo del armario suelen habitar las piezas de ropa poco usadas, que han ido cayendo en el olvido para dejar paso a otras que nos ponemos con más frecuencia.

¿Por qué, pues, usamos esta expresión?

Comment: Tratándose de un artículo de moda me juego lo que quieras a que la expresión es un préstamo del francés. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contémplalo de esta forma: según las definiciones de [*fondo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IBiSV3w) podemos decir que un "fondo" es la parte inferior de algo hueco. Curiosamente, busqué la definición de *[fondo](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fond/34470?q=fond#34417)* en francés y la primera acepción es la misma (bueno, habla de "base" en vez la parte inferior), poniendo como ejemplos *le fond d'un tonneau, d'une armoire*. Es decir, que para un armario el fondo no tiene por qué ser la parte de atrás, sino la parte inferior o base.

Ahora bien, cuando tienes un armario vacío y tienes que llenarlo de ropa, lo primero que tienes que meter es lo básico, que al ser lo primero irá a parar irremediablemente al fondo del mismo al no haber nada previo. Otra cosa ya es luego el uso que le des conforme pase el tiempo, que como tú dices al final lo que va al fondo es lo que menos se use.

Así pues, el fondo de armario se refiere a lo primero que tienes que meter en el armario. La cuestión queda más clara cuando se establece el marco temporal (el primer instante de uso del armario, más que el uso continuado con el tiempo).

Comment: ¡Pues qué bien visto! Yo me quedé con la acepción visual de fondo: al final, inalcanzable... cuando claramente es sinónimo de _base_ en este caso. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

En la séptima definición de [fondo](http://dle.rae.es/?w=fondo) en la RAE se indica:

> caudal o conjunto de bienes que posee una persona.

La ropa es un bien económico, *de armario* es mas que nada su ubicación.

Se entiende que cada persona tiene un armario, es por eso que se suele usar fondo de armario como personal.

Mira de aplicar tu lógica contra la que acabo de describir pero usando otra expresión: *fondo de inversión*, *fondo que agrupa los capitales destinados a la inversión de una pluralidad de personas*.

Aceptamos fondo de ropa destinado al uso de una persona como fondo de armario? :)